# Netbeans 7.3 Clean Install: Classpath to J2ME Ant extension library (libs.j2me_ant_ext.classpath property) is not set

Tags: ant, java-me

First of all I'd like to start by saying that I'm actually a .Net programmer, and it so happens that I need to develop a J2ME app again today. I've have had innumerable problems developing J2ME apps with Netbeans in the past, to the extent that I have had to use someone else's laptop to do the job.

Today I installed Netbeans 7.3. Clean install. I installed the WTK 2.5.2 right afterwards. I managed to configure the platform on Netbeans and all, but once I make a J2ME app and run it I'm getting the following error message:

"Classpath to J2ME Ant extension library (libs.j2me_ant_ext.classpath property) is not set."

Trust me this is quite upsetting since I've looked it up on the net, and it seems the menu items to solve that problem that people have been pointing out to DO NOT EXIST in Netbeans 7.3.

I added an ANT variable: libs.j2me_ant_ext.classpath and set it to C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\mobility\ant\nblib

Still not working. I'm not even sure if that's the correct path, if those are the correct files.

This is extremely frustrating. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problem with nb 7.2.1, it's probably a bug which destroys a part of .properties file in those versions.
Fix your properties in file `%project_folder%\nbproject\project.properties` (you can copy them from such files in similar healthy projects)